# django auth not logging in on register

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication

Struggling with my very basic django auth login system. When a new user registers, they are first redirected to `/user/user_id` as I'd like (the user is also being created fine), but they are then redirected to `/login?next=/user/user_id/` which is being done by the @login_decorator over the `user` view, (the problem stops if I remove the decorator). (nb. Debug toolbar is breaking up the redirect sequence for me to see). However, if I then manually  I include Register view below. I can't see why it is not logging in immediately upon registration. The login method seems to be all there:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'],
                                    password = request.POST['password1'])
            login(request, new_user)
            context = RequestContext(request)    
            context['user_id'] = new_user.id`
            url = '/user/%s/' % new_user.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render_to_response("registration/register.html", {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have `def login(request):` in your view?

Comment: In views.py I have: `@login_required
def log_in(request):
    url = '/user/%s/' % request.user.id
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)` but nothing else. This is surely not the problem.